# Stop client event | Discord JS

Tags: discord, discord.js

i want to stop client messageReactionAdd listening event, but i don't now how. I want to do something like this:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {

  //Previous code

  if (user.id == "1234567891234567") {
  //Stop listening event/stop messageReactionAdd listening event and do not execute again
  }

})
```

Note: I can't use `if (user.id == "1234567891234567") return`; at the beginning because I need Previous code, and i don't want use it at the end because I just want to not run this event anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `EventEmitter#removeListener()` or `EventEmitter#off()`

**removeListener()**
Assign your callback to a variable to then reference when removing the listener

```js
const callback = (reaction, user) => {
   // Your code...
};

client.removeListener('messageReactionAdd' callback);
```

**off()**

```js
client.off('messageReactionAdd');
```